# Permission denied docker-entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been with this problem for a long time and I would like to clarify this problem, since the documentation doesn't say much.

```
[FATAL tini (6)] exec /sbin/docker-entrypoint.sh failed: Permission denied
```

What is `tini`?

Why the error with the permissions?

#### *Dockerfile:*

---

```
COPY entrypoint-base.sh /sbin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--", "/sbin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know I'm a little late but seconding @ARK, you need to give execute permissions to the entrypoint.sh. But use the following command after `COPY entrypoint-base.sh /sbin/docker-entrypoint.sh` (note the lowercase chmod and a RUN command) -

```
RUN chmod +x /sbin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to give execute permissions after you copy the file to the image. Add the following line after `COPY entrypoint-base.sh /sbin/docker-entrypoint.sh` -

```
RUN chmod +x /sbin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```